# Simple XML & PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, simplexml

Hey there I have an XML file that contains some information similar to this:

```
<root>
 <library>
   <name>TestName1</name>
   <location>TestLocation1</location>
 </library>
 <library>
   <name>TestName2</name>
   <location>TestLocation2</location>
 </library>
 <book>
   <name>Book1</name>
   <author>Author1</author>
 </book>
 <book>
   <name>Book2</name>
   <author>Author2</author>
 </book>
</root>
```

what I did was create an array that would store an array of the information. However My problem lies with trying to return only books or libraries.

```
$xml = "libraries.xml";
$array_libraries = array();
$library = simplexml_load_file($xml);

foreach($library as $get_library) {
$name = $get_library->name;
$location = $get_library->location;
array_push($array_albums, array($name, $location));
}
```

I would like to keep books and libraries in the same file if possible but i only want to put libraries into the array, thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to loop over just the libraries, not just the whole XML.

Change:

```
foreach($library as $get_library) {
```

to

```
foreach($library->library as $get_library) {
```

As a side note, SimpleXML isn't the greatest for working with XML.  Look into using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead.

Comment: The preference for DOM over SimpleXML is very much a matter of taste. In my opinion, for simple read-only operations, SimpleXML does what it says on the tin.

Answer (score 0):

You define an array,

```
$array_libraries = array();
```

Then you push in another array

```
array_push($array_albums, array($name, $location));
```

Try pushing in the previously declared array:

```
array_push($array_libraries, array($name, $location));
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be useful

```
$xml = "libraries.xml";
$array_libraries = array();
$array_albums = array();
$library = simplexml_load_file( $xml );

foreach( $library as $get_library => $x ) {
    $name = $x->name;
    $location = $x->location;
    if ( $get_library === 'library' ) {
        array_push( $array_libraries, array( $name, $location ) );
    }
    if ( $get_library === 'book' ) {
        array_push( $array_albums, array( $name, $location ) );
    }
}
```

If you only want the libraries, you keep only that if and remove/comment the other one, if you want both, then you already have an example working.

Bye